# Are these cashew nuts mouldy?

Tags: cashews

I accidentally had some of these nuts without looking properly and I am now quite worried. They tasted fine - no rancid or obvious bitter taste. Are the darkened bits leftover parts of the shell (i.e. normal parts of cashew nuts) or are they mould/signs that the cashew has gone bad? When I tried to remove them, the darkened bits are crumbly rather than fuzzy.

[image]

Comment: Those darker spots look like some pieces of the inner husk are still attached to the nuts. No need to worry, it's normal.